Magento 2 Upload image from Mobile to Desktop using QR code
I have image upload field on the product page where I'm uploading the multiple images.
Now I have to give the feature there to upload the image from mobile to desktop using the QR code.
It will be as below:

The user scans the mobile QR for uploading then a new page opens on user’s mobile which will then upload the images directly on the desktop PDP page.

So I have added the QR code to open the link when scan but after this how can I upload the image and send it to desktop.
Reference to implement feature like http://post.craigslist.org/ in the fourth step
Please give me some suggestion or hints.

just to understand correctly... when you say the user scans the mobile QR means that any visitor can upload pictures to any of the products?

Yes correct Any visitor can scan the QR code then it will  give link. This link will open in the mobile. There visitor will upload the images then click on Confirm button. After click on the confirm button images will show on the product page in Desktop where user scanned the QR code.

First, I would recommend considering the security implications of allowing users to upload files to your website, especially from mobile devices. Unrestricted file uploads can pose risks such as malicious file uploads, so you'll need to implement strict validation, moderation, and security measures to prevent abuse.
That said, here's an approach you can follow to implement the feature:
Generate a QR Code: Create a QR code that encodes a signed URL containing the product SKU or other necessary identifiers. This will allow the user to scan the QR code with their mobile device. This can be done in the PDP view or added dinamically on the gallery using the correct interceptor.
Mobile Upload Page: Once the QR code is scanned, it should direct the user to a mobile-friendly upload page. This page can allow users to select images from their mobile device and upload them to a temporary server directory. All this features can be integrated into the module. You can integrate this field into the Quote of Magento and relate that with the product having the uploads related to the quote item entry.
Cart view: You can have a new item rendering element where the uploaded images can be shown for the customer. Same approach can happen with the rendering on the sideview on the checkout page.
Checkout modifications: When the order is placed, a listener needs to be set to modify the relation between the quote item with the order item that the images belongs to.
Backend modifications: to be able to review the images afterwards, will need to add the images into the order view on the backend, or create an interface where the images are listed and relate them to the order and product in particular.
Emails: emails template can be also modified to include the images if required, and even the download link to the images if the email is been sent to the person who will use the images for the printing of the personalization.
I'm pretty sure that there should be an existing module to make 80% of this (at least the relation) from which you can modify and add the QR part.

Hi @serfe, Thanks for your reply but the images going to upload is not product images.
I have custom field on the product page where customer uploads the multiple images and later on it will be processed with the add item to cart.
So when user upload the images in the mobile then it will be used for the custom image upload field.

@m2dev I've modified my response to match your last comment. I understand a little better you requirements now.

yeah We have already the functionality is working in which customer upload images from the desktop and it's saving with the quote and order Item. Need to improve it to add QR so customer can upload images directly from Mobile then send it Desktop. So main part is that how to send images to Desktop and display from where QR code was scanned. Reference to implement feature like http://post.craigslist.org/ in the fourth step

Adding an image to the product with the signed URl should not be difficult. Go get the images and show them on the frontend desktop, you need to have a container for the images which queries the backend for those specific pictures every 2 seconds to display them. On the view for the mobile url, just add an uploader into to an specific endpoint using the normal uploader. If you don't want to got into having the query every 2 seconds, you might need to use websockets to handle that specific element of the update

I also thought to do this with the websocket. It's totally new for me. I have just setup it in my local system. But after click on the button I able to receive the message in the same window. if I have to send message from one window and receive in the second window it's not working. Also I have confusion that how it will handle simultaneous message from different customers at a time. Can you give some Idea? I have to send message from mobile device and receive in the desktop device.

to link the session from the desktop with the mobile, you can have a parameter on the QR code... that's the easiest thing to handle that... Regarding WebSockets you can use the library of preference and integrate into your module. Here is an example from another question This migth require some changes into the webserver to support this or another service to run this....

Yes I'm passing the session ID with QR code link. My Query is that for simultaneous use sending message to websocket server then how to handle? Also not receiving message in the different tab but able to receive in the same tab.
